# vb.net error when im trying to insert 2 statement

Tags: vb.net

Below are my code use for update data in my database. So i can set my database status to true or false, (tick and not ticked in my database). then i need to add one more which is student id into the statement so when i insert the student id, i also insert and set the status in my database to true. when i type stundet id into the coding, it cannot run. but when i delete it and run the update accommodation status to true it will run. So i think there's problem in the stundent id part.

```
cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE Accommodation SET Status = True , Student_ID = '" & txttp.Text & "' WHERE Unit_ID = " & txtunitid.Text & ";"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should set status to 1, not True.

Secondly, you should use SqlParameters. Otherwise, you'll allow someone to attack your database using SQL Injection.

```
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StudentId", txttp.Text));
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UnitId", txtunitid.Text));
cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE Accommodation SET Status = 1 , Student_ID =  @StudentId WHERE Unit_ID = @UnitId;"
```

Comment: well.. this is a easy assignment assigned tho, my teacher dint teach me those sql things, so we;re basically connect database created by microsoft access to the vb.net. i tried set status to 1 but it diddn't work out until i replace 1 to true.

Comment: See if you can find the actual error message and post it

Comment: It says No value given for one or more required parameters. i tried put 'True' but it cannot run also